# how can I switch two menuItems in wpf with Icommand

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, mvvm, icommand

I have two menuItems that binded to the  same command "show picture" and "hide picture" and I would like that any time there will be only one Item shown or show or hide.

the syntax of Execute is the same except the parameter.

Is it possible that I can show only one at same time and if I am pressing the item it will switch to the other one?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind Visibility to the other controls visibility using ElementName. Then use a converter to flip the visibility.

```
Visibility="{Binding ElementName=otherControl,Path=Visibility,Converter={StaticResource HiddenToVisibleConverter}}"
```

Comment: this is what I tried... should I made both of the menuitem CanExcute always enabled?

Comment: try NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True